# Need a shell/python script for this logic

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to put together a shell/python hack for the following logic:

1. I have a file with a list of IMEI which are 14-15 digit long.

   Ex:-

   ```
   123456872932343
   82342512435234
   230098234242342
   82341436242422
   ```
2. I need to examine the first 8 digits of each of the above lines in the file and categorize them as a model.

   For example:-

   123456872932343 --> the first 8 digits 12345687 will indicate a certain model--say "Model-X"
3. I need to iterate through this list to analyze the first 8 digits, categorize it as a  model and then if the 8 digits repeat in the list, then the count of the model needs to be increased.

Can someone please help in this regard.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It sounds like a job for `sed` (to collect the first 8 digits) and `sort` (to group repeats together) and `uniq -c` to count the number of repeats for each model.  What's the problem?

Comment: Elon, is that you again, or is it just me over-thinking Tesla. :3

Answer (score 2):

Will the following code work for you?

```
#!/bin/python
dict_model = {  'model-X': '12345687',
                'model-Y': '98765432'}
count_model = {  'model-X': 0,
                'model-Y': 0}
imei_list = ['123456872932343', '123456876846461', '123456876846462', '987654326846461', '987654326846462']

for x in imei_list:
    for model in dict_model:
        if dict_model[model] == x[0:8]:
            count_model[model]+=1

print(count_model)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Mr Vinu. I did try a similar approach. I realized that the issue is that the Dictionary containing the IMEI mapping to the model number is not exhaustive and hence I ended up having a lot of IMEI mappings to an unknown model. The glitch is on my side. Thanks for the Code.

Answer (score 0):

You could count these in a dict checking the first 8 digits :

```
list_of_numbers=["1111111111","5454545454","1111111111","4545454545","1111111111","4545454545","6666666666"]
counts={}
for i in list_of_numbers:    
    counts[i[:8]]=counts.get(i[:8],0)+1
print(counts)
```

Output:

```
{'111111111': 3, '545454545': 1, '454545454': 2, '666666666': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, One of the issues that i had was in the conversion of the IMEI into the corresponding manufacturer. The wiki page for IMEI TAC(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_Allocation_Code ) does not give an exhaustive list of TAC to Operator mapping and this where a lot of my tagging was going into an unknown bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pseudocode :

```
file = open(path/to/textfile , 'r')
imeis = [i.strip() for i in file.readlines()]
models = [model_int1 , model_int2, ...]
imei_dict = {}
for j in models:
    temp = []
    for i in imeis:
        if int(i[:8]) == j:
            temp.append(i)            
    imei_dict[j] = temp
```

Output should be :

```
imei_dict = {model_int1 : [list of all imei with that model] , model_int2 : [...]}
```

If you want to get the number of imei number corresponding to certain models, try this :

```
imei_count = {k:len(imei_dict[k]) for k in imei_dict }
```